# How to check if a non-negative matrix is primitive (in the stochastic sense)?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

A square non-negative matrix $A$ is *primitive* if $A^k$ has all entries positive for some positive integer $k$. Is there an algorithm to do this check in practice? Given a non-negative square matrix $A$ of finite dimension $N$, can we determine if it is primitive?

**Note:** By non-negative matrix $A$, I mean that all its entries are non-negative.

Comment: This seems to be hard, but maybe there is some insight involving eigen-anaysis

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0729.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corollary 8.5.8 in Horn & Johnson, Matrix Analysis.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ non-negative matrix. Then $A$ is primitive if and only if $A^{n^2 - 2n + 2}$ has only positive entries.